# Error with encoding categorical data in order

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

Data source [text](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/iamsouravbanerjee/heart-attack-prediction-dataset)
I am trying to encode the categorical data columns sex with Ohe and Blood Pressure and Diet with Oe, and then scale the data before passing it through a classifier in a pipeline.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import (
    OrdinalEncoder,
    OneHotEncoder,
    MinMaxScaler,
    StandardScaler,
)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np
from sklearn import set_config

set_config(display="diagram")
data = pd.read_csv("/content/heart_attack_prediction_dataset.csv")
data.shape
data = data.drop(["Patient ID", "Country", "Continent", "Hemisphere", "Income"], axis=1)


data["Blood Pressure"][0]

bp_list = []
for each in data["Blood Pressure"]:
    bp = each.split("/")
    systolic = int(bp[0])

    diastolic = int(bp[1])

    if systolic < 120 and diastolic < 80:
        bp_list.append("Normal")
    elif systolic > 120 and systolic < 139 and diastolic > 80 and diastolic < 89:
        bp_list.append("Pre Hypertension")
    elif systolic > 140 and systolic < 159 and diastolic > 90 and diastolic < 99:
        bp_list.append("Stage 1 Hypertension")
    else:
        bp_list.append("Stage 2 Hypertension")


data["Blood Pressure"] = bp_list


# Encoding Sex

trf1_ohe = ColumnTransformer(
    [("ohe", OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown="ignore"), [1])],
    remainder="passthrough",
)
# Encoding Categorical Data column
trf2_oe = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        (
            "oe",
            OrdinalEncoder(
                categories=[
                    [
                        "Normal",
                        "Pre Hypertension",
                        "Stage 1 Hypertension",
                        "Stage 2 Hypertension",
                    ],
                    ["Good", "Average", "Unhealthy"],
                ],
                handle_unknown="use_encoded_value",
                unknown_value=np.nan,
            ),
            [4, 11],
        )
    ],
    remainder="passthrough",
)

# Scaling

trf3_scal = ColumnTransformer(
    [("scaling", StandardScaler(), [0, 3, 8, 20])], remainder="passthrough"
)

trf4_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

pipe = Pipeline(
    [("trf1", trf1_ohe), ("trf2", trf2_oe), ("trf3", trf3_scal), ("trf4", trf4_clf)]
)

pipe

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data.drop(columns=["Heart Attack Risk"]),
    data["Heart Attack Risk"],
    test_size=0.3,
    random_state=11,
)

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

trf1 is a columntransformer for Ohe on the sex column, trf2 is column transformer to Oe on blood pressure and diet column and trf3 is columntransformer to scale the data

A pipeline is created with trf1,trf2,trf3,trf4 and when I am trying to fit the data I am getting error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Average'
```

What went wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: `X_train` is a pandas dataframe and `y_train` is a pandas series. Were you expecting this ?

Comment: Also, the dataframe in the `X_train` contains strings in some of the columns. Try to remove those columns and report if that works or not...

Comment: Where exactly? Please edit your question to include the full error trace (and remove any code that may come *after* the error) - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because you use multiple `ColumnTransformer`s in your pipeline. When `trf1_ohe` is fit it creates an array with your one-hot encoded values for Sex as its two columns and then appends the remaining columns to the right because you specified the remainder should be passed through. As a result, the index of your columns has now shifted and Diet is no longer the column at index 11!

You could solve this by fitting each step separately to figure out the new indices of your columns. This will be confusing, though, since the output of `ColumnTransformer` is an array (so no column names) and the second application of it in your pipeline (`trf2_oe`) will *again* move the columns it applies to to left side of the DataFrame and append the remainder (so the index will change a second time).

Another approach would be to use only one `ColumnTransformer` in your final pipeline.

Here's one way you might do this (note this is untested with your specific data):

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data.drop(columns=["Heart Attack Risk"]),
    data["Heart Attack Risk"],
    test_size=0.3,
    random_state=11,
)

ohe = Pipeline(
    steps=[("ohe", OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown="ignore"))]
)
oe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        (
            "oe",
            OrdinalEncoder(
                categories=[
                    [
                        "Normal",
                        "Pre Hypertension",
                        "Stage 1 Hypertension",
                        "Stage 2 Hypertension",
                    ],
                    ["Good", "Average", "Unhealthy"],
                ],
                handle_unknown="use_encoded_value",
                unknown_value=np.nan,
            ),
        )
    ]
)
num = Pipeline(steps=[("scaling", StandardScaler())])

preprocess = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("ohe", ohe, ["Sex"]),
        ("oe", oe, ["Blood Pressure", "Diet"]),
        ("num", num, ["Age", "Cholesterol", "Obesity"]),
    ],
    remainder = "passthrough"
)

pipe = Pipeline(
    [("transform", preprocess), ("model", trf4_clf)]
)

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```